# How to fix "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object" in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, axios

I'm having a problem of getting the object property from the front-end passed by axios to PHP laravel resource controller.

```
axios({
   method:post,
   url: ...
   data: {
     obj: {id:1,name:'Foo',age:25}
   }
})
```

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $res = $request->obj->id;
        return $res;
    }
```

I expect return value is 1, but in the console it says "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object".

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

This is because the `obj` variables is an array instead of an object. The solution to your problem is:

`return $request->obj['id'];`

**Extra explanation**

When calling a property on the `Request` instance of Laravel which doesn't exist a magic method called `__get()` is being called. This method checks if the property which you've just called exists in the request body. If so it will return that value. When sending objects or array to the your Laravel app, the Request (or better said PHP) receive those values as an array. That's why you need to access the id variable via an array and not via an object.

By the way, if the id hasn't been send in the `obj` variable within the request body, the code will fail because it to key doesn't exist. You might want to validate the data of the request body. Read more in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation).

Comment: Thank you! I've tried also ```$res = (object) $request->obj; return $res->id``` and it worked. What should I use if it's in the case of time consuming process??

Comment: Glad it worked out. You can select my answer as working solution so it might help other people in the future too. About the object to array casting, I don't think it's very time consuming. Depends on how big the array is really. Otherwise you can just use it as an array instead.